# Collect several input fields and insert into a single field with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 4 input textfields, and a single textfield that should collect values from each.

```
<input type="text" class="collector">

<input type="text" class="collected">
<input type="text" class="collected">
<input type="text" class="collected">
<input type="text" class="collected">
```

The **collected** inputs are text and expected to be inserted into **collector** as is. 
So NULL should be sent too along with those with values.

The collector expects to look like:
**Data 1 | Null | Data 3 | Data 4**

So Null is accepted when no value is given, simply to maintain the process of explode and implode by PHP.

I am stuck, my jquery only picks one of them, because I don't know how to aggregate the separate collected values into an array:

```
$('input.collector').val($(".collected").text());
```

Any hint is very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input.collector').val(function() {
    return $(".collected").map(function() {
        return $(this).val() || 'NULL';
    }).get().join('|');
});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/DDQ8s/

Comment: Wow, nice answer.  Way to combine native js and jquery very well.

Answer (score 2):

```
var text= "";
$(".collected").each(function(){
   text += "|" + $(this).val();
});

$(".collector").val(text.substring(1,text.length));
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nT8NF/

Comment: Thanks, but I got the results: undefined | Data 1 || Data 3 | Data 4. Its okay that Null is just empty. But out of 4 fields I recieved 5 (strangely the first is always: undefined). Thanks again

Comment: I just updated the code give it another try and take a look at the fiddle.  I wrote that off the top of my head.

Comment: Yes, working perfectly now. I need a Null better than empty though for end user readablity, although empty is more efficient. Thanks a lot