# Extraxt values and distribute with jquery

Tags: jquery

This question is the **opposite** of [Collect several input fields and insert into a single field with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135079/collect-several-input-fields-and-insert-into-a-single-field-with-jquery/9135129#9135129)

I have 4 input textfields, and a single textfield that should extract its value and distribute them into each separate input using index.
I am expecting a reverse process (from the previous question) to get default value from **distributor** to be distributed/ populated into **distributed** textfield. Each value is pipe delimited.

```
<input type="text" value="Data 1 | Null | Data 3 | Data 4" class="distributor">

<input type="text" class="distributed">
<input type="text" class="distributed">
<input type="text" class="distributed">
<input type="text" class="distributed">
```

The distributor has an array-like value string: Data 1 | Null | Data 3 | Data 4

Null is accepted from original process, simply to maintain the process of explode and implode by PHP.

So input#1 will recieve Data 1, etc in an indexed manner, hopefully, because the order is fixed and using **name** attributes seems redundant.

Any hint is very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example with jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bouillard/NWUxq/

can be extend for null values.

Comment: Thanks, a lot. The answers are similar, and you came early. Thank you very much. Seems so easy when you know how.

Answer (score 2):

Easy - http://jsfiddle.net/akgnR/

Jquery's each() function comes with an index, use that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var arr = $(".distributor").val().split("|");
    $(".distributed").each(function(index){
        $(this).val(arr[index])
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var valArr = ["Data 1 ", " Null ", " Data 3 ", " Data 4"];

$(":input").each(function(i){
    $(this).val(valArr[i]);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/n6grp/8/)

---

```
var valArr = $(":input").val().split('|');

$(":input:not(:eq(0))").each(function(i){
    $(this).val(valArr[i]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/n6grp/10/